# Elequent ORM ->where and ->save

Tags: laravel, orm, models

I am new to Eloquent, and still getting my head round it, before i put the 'where' clause it it was working fine now i cant seem to get it to work.

```
$filesRelationship = self::user()->customer->submissions->where('period_timestamp', '=', Input::get('period_timestamp'))->customerfile();


     $customerFile = new Customerfile(
               array('path' => $savepath, 'document_id' => Input::get('document_id')
               )
        );

    $customerFileResult = $filesRelationship->save($customerFile);
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the relationships from your Models (you did not specify them), but this could work:

```
$filesRelationship = self::user()
    ->customer()
    ->submissions()
    ->where('period_timestamp', '=', Input::get('period_timestamp'))
    ->customerfile()
    ->first();
```